# MVC ActionLink calling multiple JQuery functions

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to call a confirm, then an alert function from an MVC action link and I'm stuck.  The code is as follows:

My view has the following actionlink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("JQuery Testing", "BuildProject", Model, new { onclick = " return ConfirmProjectSubmit()" })
```

which calls the controller to save a project to the database.  I'm trying to throw a confirm statement onClick.  Once that action is performed, the following action is called:

```
return RedirectToAction("ProjectDetails", "Project", new RouteValueDictionary(new { id = currentProject.Id, msg = message }));
```

to alert the user that the project was actually created.

and then at the bottom of my view:

```
@section scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
        function ConfirmWorkflowSubmit() {
            $.confirm({
                title: 'Confirm!',
                content: 'Simple confirm!',
                buttons: {
                    confirm: function () {

                    },
                    cancel: function () {

                    }
                }
            });
        return false;
        };
</script>

@if (ViewBag.message != null)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $.alert({
            title: 'Workflow successfully created',
            content: '@ViewBag.message',
            type: 'green',
            });
        });
    </script>
}
}
```

both of the actions are firing, but incorrectly.  I'm newer to MVC and moreso to Jquery.  Basically I need to figure out how to not have it submit if the user doesn't confirm, and then make sure the message only pops on the way back.  I think I just need help ordering what I have properly.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT.  Okay, so I see part of the problem.  It's not the $confirm function that's actually submitting the form, it's the button action clicked once the dialog is open.  I'm really stuck here, and this has to be easier than I'm making it.  Help!

Comment: Try passing the event to the function, looks like `function(event){...}` pass it in to the `cancel: function(event)` and then use `event.preventDefault();`.

Comment: Sorry, can you please dumb that down.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying you can't do it the way you have, but this is normally how I set up my bindings:

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    // add the e here -- it is the event which initiated the binding
    $(".buildButton").on("click", function (e) 
    {
        if (ConfirmProjectSubmit())
        {
            alert('confirm');

        }
        else
        {
            // e.preventDefault() cancels the click action
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('cancel');
        }
    });
});
function ConfirmProjectSubmit()
{
    // some confirm logic
    // return true for confirmed, false for cancelled
    return false;
}
```

Remove the `onclick` in your action.  There is no need to have a jQuery binding *and* an onClick.

This is sort of an outline, you can add your logic in various places to finish it out.